# (1,2) is a subset of (0, 3), but how can I represent this in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

(1,2) is a subset of (0, 3), but how can I represent this in SymPy?

```
a = Interval(1,2)
b = Interval(0,3)
```

I want to represent `a` is a subset of `b` in SymPy, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: Thank you for for your editing, but I want to represent subset in SymPy not determine.

Comment: My apologies, I edited again to stick to your original wording - what exactly do you mean by "represent" subset then?

Comment: In Sympy, there is a Union class which can represent union of two set, but there is no subset class to represent set A is a subset of set B.

Comment: Sure, but what would the use of such a class be? A subset isn't a compound set like a union or an intersection is, and so has no "compound representation" nor any reduction that can occur. What are you actually trying to _do_?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether `a` is a subset of `b` directly with [`is_subset`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#sympy.sets.sets.Set.is_subset).

```
>>> Interval(1, 2).is_subset(Interval(0, 3))
True
```

There are a vast number of other set operations in [SymPy.sets](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#module-sympy.sets.sets).